# CSS absolute positioning in the parent and child

Tags: css, html

I understand that by setting the parent div to `position:relative`, if I make the position of the child absolute, than the child's position will be absolute within the parent. If I want to make the grandchild positioned absolutely within child, how would I do that, since child is already set to `position:absolute`? Sorry if this question is weird, any help appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child">
<div id="grandchild"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
position:relative;
}
#child{
position:absolute;
}
#grandchild{
}
```

Comment: Sorry! The Html above would be something like this: <div id="parent">
<div id="child">
<div id="grandchild"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can edit your own question by clicking the `edit` link below the `html`, `css`, and `div` tags. For more information on how to use this site, please [read this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: An absolute position requires a parent position other than default (static) to position it to something other than the root. By setting the child's position to absolute, you already effectively set the grandchild's parent's position as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why would you need to put another `div` inside the child? Just absolute position that one and use `z-index` to layer them

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one 'position:absolute;'in nested elements without regard to the positioning of the parent element. Each time you use absolute, you set that divs position relative to the dimensions of its parent element. The parent element can be relative, absolute, or fixed (anything but static) and it should not affect its children nodes.

I mention this just so that you do not mistakenly think that the relative positioning of #parent has any bearing on the absolute positioning of #child, and the #grandchild element can be positioned as absolute OR relative, just keep in mind that you are positioning it to the dimensions of the #child, and in reference to its immediate parent.

The short answer, set #grandchild{position:absolute;} and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

An absolute position element is positioned relative to it's parent element (except if parent has position set to static, but it's not your case), then:

```
#grandchild{
    position: absolute;
}
```

will set grandchild's position absolute in relative to child - just as you want?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, if you want to manipulate more. I made you an example of positioning.

Here is jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Be84P/1/

```
#parent{
position:relative;
height:200px;
background: blue;
}
#child{
position:absolute;
top: 20;
width:20px;
height:100px;
background: red;
}
#grandchild{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
height: 50px;
background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it does vary on what type of project your working on, but layering or making a list out of it might help. `z-index:` in CSS, or an ordered list,

in HTML.